# Using XML to take inputs for shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, parameters

I have a shell script that requires user to provide 5-6 parameters as inputs. 
How can I get all these 5-6 parameters from an XML file?

What changes will I make to my script (currently it uses "read") so that It will one by one select the parameters from the file and then assign it to the respective variables to be used further?

(At a later stage the web interface will be developed which will produce the xml file; so I have the liberty of assuming that parameters will be made available to me in whatever way/order that I want ; of course within the bounds of the XML syntax)

Comment: You can use [xmlstarlet](http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/xml_starlet/) to extract values from xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is plenty of tools allowing to parse XML with Bash.
XML (`foo.xml'):

```
<egg>Foo</egg>
```

I would use `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath '//egg/text()' foo.xml
Foo
```

To install `xmllint` on debian:

```
apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-utils
```

Comment: Ah, no, don't parse xml in bash like that. You xml tools such as xmlstarlet instead.